# Want to have a password input screen just like the unlock the device interface

Tags: iphone, passwords, locking

I'd like to design a password input screen and I'd like the "unlock device" interface. How to implement it in iphone SDK? Any sample code? I can't find the four square box that in IB. Shall I build it my own?

Answer (score 2):

KVPasscodeViewController (mine), is available here: https://github.com/Koolistov/Passcode (BSD license).

Comment: Your license is a bit confusing, at least when it comes to distributing apps that use your code on the app store. Do you require developers to display the copyright notice inside their apps?

Comment: @joshaidan Not sure what is confusing. Distributing via App Store is in binary form. The copyright notices/license is expected to be shown in the app in that case. (Inside an Acknowledgements section in the Settings like many Apple apps do would count too.)

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure about this part, "this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution." So in addition to an acknowledgement, those three conditions need to be included as well.

Comment: @joshaidan Normal practice is to just include the whole contents of the license file.